# Multimodule Groovy web application

Tags: web-applications, groovy

I about to create a multi-module Groovy web application. It should consists of the following parts:

```
* a web frontend,
* a simple web crawler.
```

The web frontend would communicate with the crawler through a relational database.

I am new to the world of Groovy. **Could you recommend technologies to use (e.g. build system, web framework, etc.) which would fit well together?**

---

I wanted to build the web application on Grails and use Gradle to build the whole project. I wasn't able to make the two tools cooperate though.

Comment: Multi-module in what sense? It doesn't sound like they're tightly-related components. In any case, I tend towards Maven or Gradle.

Comment: Grails 2.x already uses Gradle under the covers so you won't have to manually integrate them.

Comment: @Dave Newton: The application is composed of two basic components - the web frontend and the crawler. They both need to be installed for the application to work correctly. They are loosely coupled though - they communicate indirectly via a relational database. In addition to that, I might want to extract some code pieces which would support coherent functionality from the web frontend codebase into JAR files. The web frontend would have a compile scoped dependency on them.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle suits your needs the best.

You can find more information regrading multi-project builds here: http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html

Regarding Groovy compilation you can read here:
http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/groovy_plugin.html

Regarding WebApp handling you can read here:
http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/war_plugin.html

**UPDATE**: There is also an interesting post (it's a bit old, but is still valid) here:

http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/11/gradle-goodness-groovy-multi-project.html